# ie background color with height shows on full page

Tags: css

I have this very simply CSS code.

```
body {
    background-color: #08407A;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

This one doesn't work in IE at all. The background is fully colored, but I need only background for `500px`. I have tried all that `background-cover`, `behavior`. But it didn't work out for me.

Comment: It will not work like that.

Whatever colour you give for body will be shown across the page. To show color only for 500px you need to add a div with height 500px and give background color to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the body as fixed width container.

Limiting the width of body doesn't make sense, as it represents the entire browser window.

Instead, try using a block element, such as a `<div>` to achieve your results.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myDiv">
   This is my content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv { background-color:#08407A; min-width:1000px; height:500px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working directly with `body` isn't good idea. Instead, use an element:

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
            HTML DATA
    </div>
</body>
```

---

### CSS

```
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #08407A;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/rf3d8/).

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like that.

Whatever colour you give for body will be shown across the page. To show color only for 500px you need to add a div with height 500px and give background color to it.

But if you don't want to use a div and you are using a modern browser you can try something like this using background style

http://jsfiddle.net/hZfJJ/1/

```
body {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,61,61,1) 0%, rgba(255,61,61,1) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,61,61,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(255,61,61,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,61,61,1) 0%,rgba(255,61,61,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,61,61,1) 0%,rgba(255,61,61,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,61,61,1) 0%,rgba(255,61,61,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,61,61,1) 0%,rgba(255,61,61,1) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 40%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3d3d', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    height:100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```